# Email vs http: line endings

Tags: http, smtp

Suppose you have a plain content part:

```
Header: value
Header: value

content...
```

In HTTP, there is no requirement to add an additional "\r\n\r\n" at the end of the content ([Should newline be included in http response content length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821263/should-newline-be-included-in-http-response-content-length)), it uses only content-length (or chunked) to determine the size of the message.

However the question is: is it necessary for email? I can't find the exact place in the (many) rfcs related to mail that define how a "normal" content part should end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIME content parts end just before the newline before the content separator. Thus in the following fragment

```
--moo

Foo
--moo

Bar

--moo--
```

... the first part lacks a trailing newline, whereas the second ends with one.

Pre-MIME messages were not explicitly standardized on this particular point; but due to the requirements of SMTP, it wasn't possible to transmit a message which didn't have a final newline at the end.

Comment: Ok, I take from this that I will leave the trailing linefeeds when constructing mail. Thanks!